# How to handle timeout error in HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-http

I am using an `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` for connecting with an external service. Here is my code:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "authTokenRequestJsonChannel")
    @Bean
    public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler ucicAuthTokenFetchOutbound() {
        final HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(
                "http://10.10.10.10:8032/apiv3/dataapi/Login");
        handler.setExpectedResponseType(ResponseDto.class);
        handler.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        return handler;
    }
```

This generates the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@410142f3]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://10.8.10.53:8032/apiv3/dataapi/Login": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={id=[0875-0000-0007-612]}, headers={http_requestMethod=GET, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1064c12b, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1064c12b, Accept=*/*, Cache-Control=no-cache, Connection=keep-alive, User-Agent=PostmanRuntime/7.26.8, http_requestUrl=http://localhost:8085/api/v1/ucic/fetchUcicCustomerData/?id=0875-0000-0007-612, Host=localhost:8085, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, id=87557eba-a984-a322-f927-3526acd3757b, timestamp=1606103486469}]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at com.mgl.app.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:38)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor' [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@410142f3]; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://10.8.10.53:8032/apiv3/dataapi/Login": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:515)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:486)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:297)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:253)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://10.8.10.53:8032/apiv3/dataapi/Login": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:714)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchange(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:444)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:318)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:266)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:229)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:515)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:486)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:624)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:524)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:513)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.fetchAuthTokenFromUcic(Unknown Source)
    at com.mgl.app.integration.service.IntegrationUtils.getUcicAuthenticationTokenForEmployee(IntegrationUtils.java:87)
    at com.mgl.app.integration.service.UcicIntegrationService.ucicCustomerDataFetchActivator(UcicIntegrationService.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:581)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:477)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:355)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:108)
    ... 110 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739)
    ... 165 common frames omitted
```

What is the right way to deal with this timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an errorChannel to whatever starts the flow (gateway etc) or add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to the message handler.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice

> The final supplied advice class is the `o.s.i.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`. This advice is more general than the other two advices. It provides a mechanism to evaluate an expression on the original inbound message sent to the endpoint. Separate expressions are available to be evaluated, after either success or failure. Optionally, a message containing the evaluation result, together with the input message, can be sent to a message channel.

> A typical use case for this advice might be with an `<ftp:outbound-channel-adapter/>`, perhaps to move the file to one directory if the transfer was successful or to another directory if it fails: